# Is $IDENTITY documented and reliable in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, identity

I learned that SQL Server can return the value of the (single) identity column of a table using the pseudo-column `$IDENTITY`:

```
SELECT $IDENTITY FROM Table
```

Is this feature documented and reliable? The only official mention of it is on the [`IDENTITY` page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775(v=sql.110).aspx) but it's buried in a code sample. This suggest that it might be intended to be undocumented. There are remarkably few Google matches for this feature as well.

Answer (score 14):

`$IDENTITY` (and `$ROWGUID`) are documented in [SELECT Clause (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176104.aspx).

I would caution against using it because it will throw an error when a table doesn't have an identity column. Take these two examples - the first one works (check your Results tab), but the second one throws an error:

```
CREATE TABLE #EmployeesWithIdentity (EmployeeID INT IDENTITY(1,1), EmployeeName VARCHAR(50));
SELECT $IDENTITY FROM #EmployeesWithIdentity;
GO

CREATE TABLE #Employees (EmployeeName VARCHAR(50));
SELECT $IDENTITY FROM #Employees;
GO
```

Here's what the second one produces:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Invalid column name '$IDENTITY'.
```

If you're looking to find which columns have an identity field, I'd use the method described in [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87747/how-do-you-determine-what-sql-tables-have-an-identity-column-programatically) instead:

```
select COLUMN_NAME, TABLE_NAME
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
and COLUMNPROPERTY(object_id(TABLE_NAME), COLUMN_NAME, 'IsIdentity') = 1
order by TABLE_NAME
```

Or, using the catalog views:

```
SELECT s.name,t.name,c.name
FROM sys.schemas AS s 
JOIN sys.tables AS t ON s.[schema_id] = t.[schema_id]
JOIN sys.identity_columns AS c ON t.[object_id] = c.[object_id];
```